# Deploy laravel app on heroku - push rejected

Tags: php, git, laravel, heroku

I am trying to deploy a laravel app to heroku but I am currently facing a weird issue. I am getting `push rejected, failed to compile php app`. I have followed the documentation stating to add `heroku git:remote -a dealandpack` for existing repos then `git push heroku master` and even tried adding the `-f` flag. After uploading and downloading dependencies, I am stuck with this error.

This is the first push to heroku so it's not behind the head or something like that. For the `Laracast\Generators`, I have checked the `AppServiceProvider.php` and made sure it is registered but still nothing works.

What is the meaning of `pre-receive hook delined`? and why is the push rejected?

What steps should I follow to fix that?

[image: Error screenshot]